# Where is object reference variable (inside a ) stored?

Tags: memory-management, jvm

I am now learning JVM memory model.I have a question:

`package com;
public class TestAllocation {
    private static final int _1MB = 1204*1024;
public static void main(String[] args){
    testAllocation();
}
public static void testAllocation(){
    byte[] allocation1,allocation2,allocation3,allocation4;
    allocation1 = new byte[2 * _1MB];
    allocation2 = new byte[2 * _1MB];
    allocation3 = new byte[2 * _1MB];
    allocation4 = new byte[2 * _1MB];
}
}`

So ,where does reference allocation1,allocation2 stored? Since testAllocation() is a **static** method ,so ,variable inside this function is stored in **method area**?But every time a function is called, it is the **stack** push/pop operation.So , allocation1 ,allocation is stored in
the **stack frame of testAllocation()**?

But one thing is clear ,that is ,the array value ,is stored in **java heap** ,right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Making the method static does not change where its variables are stored.

At the end of `testAllocation()` there will be four references (allocation1, allocation2, allocation3 and allocation4) on the stack.

These four references will refer to four byte arrays that are stored on the heap.